# When i used webdriver sampler in jmeter for this code,i got blank window

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

When i used webdriver sampler in jmeter for this code,i got blank window,Please give me the solution

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://duckduckgo.com')
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_form_input_homepage'))
searchField.click()
searchField.sendKeys(['blazemeter'])
var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_button_homepage'))
button.click()
var link = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.ByCssSelector('#r1-0 > div.links_main > h2 > a.large > b'))
link.click()
WDS.log.info(WDS.name + ' has logged an entry');
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you experience any problems with JMeter the first place to look for the cause is *jmeter.log* file which usually lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

The most frequent problem is Firefox and Selenium libraries mismatch as Firefox is being updated more frequently and Selenium support is few versions behind.

In order to determine supported version:

1. Determine underlying Selenium version by looking for "selenium-*" files under /lib folder of your JMeter installation. For instance latest WebDriver plugins come with Selenium 2.46.0
2. Look into [Selenium Java changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) and see supported Firefox version.
3. Download supported Firefox version from [Mozilla FTP website](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox) and install it somewhere.
4. Edit *system.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) and add the following line there:

   ```
   webdriver.firefox.bin=/path/to/firefox/executable
   ```
5. Restart JMeter - everything should be working fine.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks